# Asp.net Core Email Sender is not working in Registration page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm trying to setup an asp.net core razor page app with using asp.net identity.

I have everything set up and I'm trying to generate the email for registration, but the code for:

```
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",  $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(value: callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

is not being hit. Like it won't even debug into it period and therefore my email for registration is not being sent or generated. The values are saving in my SQL Server database without any issues.

Here is the setup that I have going:

appsetting.js

[image]

Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the entry point of the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the host builder.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
               Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                  {
                      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                  })
                  .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                  {
                      logging.ClearProviders();
                      logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                  })
                  .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
}
```

Starup.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Startup
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Startup"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The configuration.</param>
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configuration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The configuration.
        /// </value>
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the services.
        /// // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">The services.</param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services
                .AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

            // Added for identity set up - core27
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

            services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
            services.Configure<SessionTimeoutSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SessionTimeoutSettings"));
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            // not sure what this is for?
            //services.AddDevExpressControls();

            // Auto Mapper Configurations
            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddMaps(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
                cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            });

            var sessionTimeout = Convert.ToDouble(Configuration.GetSection("SessionTimeoutSettings").GetSection("SessionTimeout").Value);
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionTimeout);
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the specified application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The application.</param>
        /// <param name="env">The env.</param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            // Added for identity set up - core27
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "node_modules")),
                RequestPath = "/node_modules",
            });
        }
    }
}
```

EmailSender.cs

```
#pragma warning disable SA1649 // File name should match first type name
    public interface IEmailSender
#pragma warning restore SA1649 // File name should match first type name
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the email asynchronous.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="email">The email.</param>
        /// <param name="subject">The subject.</param>
        /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
        /// <returns>Task</returns>
        Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// EmailSender
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="MORE.Website.Service.IEmailSender" />
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The email settings
        /// </summary>
        private readonly EmailSettings emailSettings;

        /// <summary>
        /// The env
        /// </summary>
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EmailSender"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="emailSettings">The email settings.</param>
        /// <param name="env">The env.</param>
        public EmailSender(
            IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings,
            IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            this.emailSettings = emailSettings.Value;
            this.env = env;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the email asynchronous.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="email">The email.</param>
        /// <param name="subject">The subject.</param>
        /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">InvalidOperationException</exception>
        /// <returns>Task</returns>
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();

                mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailSettings.SenderName, emailSettings.SenderFromAddress));

                mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email));

                mimeMessage.Subject = subject;

                mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("html")
                {
                    Text = message,
                };

                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        // The third parameter is useSSL (true if the client should make an SSL-wrapped
                        // connection to the server; otherwise, false).
                        // set to false for testing.
                        await client.ConnectAsync(emailSettings.MailServer, emailSettings.MailPort, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await client.ConnectAsync(emailSettings.MailServer);
                    }

                    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                    await client.AuthenticateAsync(emailSettings.Sender, emailSettings.Password);

                    await client.SendAsync(mimeMessage);

                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Registration.cshtml

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Svc27M.Areas.Identity.Data;
    using Svc27M.Services;
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<Svc27MUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<Svc27MUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<Svc27MUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<Svc27MUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new Svc27MUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",  $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(value: callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.").ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

There was an `IEmailSender` interface within:

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
```

And my `IEmailSender` was not pointing to the local one I made.

Below is the change and the fix.

Emails are sending now properly for the Registration.

Here is my code change:

[image]